# Adding values from a JavaScript object as classes on an element

Tags: javascript, object, properties

In JavaScript, how would I take the values of an object and add each one as a separate class on an element in the DOM?

For instance, let's say I have this object:

```js
const METADATA = {
    foo: 'test1',
    bar: 'test2'
};
```

I want to add the values present within this object as two separate classes on the `<html>` tag.

In order to achieve this, I tried to specify the properties of the METADATA object within the jQuery `.addClass` method:

```js
$('html').addClass( METADATA["foo","bar"] );
```

But this only added the last value of the object as a class on the `<html>` tag, which has left me fairly confused.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`METADATA["foo","bar"]` only gets the value of the `bar` property, because you're using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which is a bit odd: It evaluates its first operand (`"foo"`), throws that value away, then evaluates its second operand (`"bar"`) and takes that as its result. So it's the same as `METADATA["bar"]` or `METADATA.bar` (because evaluating `"foo"` has no side-effects).

Instead, you need to get each value separately:

```
$('html').addClass([METADATA.foo, METADATA.bar]);
```

That works because `addClass` allows you to provide an array of class names to add. (Alternatively, just call `addClass` twice.)

Or without jQuery:

```
document.documentElement.classList.add(METADATA.foo, METADATA.bar);
```

The `add` method of `DOMTokenList` allows you to specify multiple class names to add as discrete arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I assumed that `$('html').addClass( METADATA["foo","bar"] );` would have simply got both `METADATA.foo` and `METADATA.bar` at the same time, but I guess not.